# How do I assemble on github page instead of jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, assemble

Hello I need build static page for exhibition.

I aleardy use jekyll with my static site.

but..

I want to use assemble, I found someone use assemble on github static page..

I think "github pages" use only html, js, css .. becuase It will be available idea...

I found site using assemble without jekyll on github pages..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Assemble` will not be processed by Github Pages. That means that you have to :

- generate your site locally
- pull the resulting files to github
- add an empty `.nojekyll` file at the root of you repository.

And Go!

Comment: Thanks I will try with your guides.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll is processed when you push content to a specially named branch within your repository. As cool as it would be for GitHub to process Assemble like this, they don't —so you have to run it on your machine and upload the build.

First, create a new gh-pages branch.

`git checkout --orphan gh-pages`

Then, generate your site using either the Assemble CLI or the gulp-assemble/grunt-assemble plugin to that branch and push it to GitHub.

You can completely opt out of Jekyll processing by creating a file named `.nojekyll` in the root of your Page repository and pushing that file to GitHub. This should only be necessary if your site uses directories that begin with an underscore, as Jekyll sees these as special directories and does not copy them to the final destination.

Checkout the [assemble/assemble.io](https://github.com/assemble/assemble.io/tree/gh-pages) repo as an example.

Sources:

- [Using Jekyll with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/)
- [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com)